# A problem on sequence of supspaces of X and its dual space

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, operator-theory, dual-spaces

$X$ is a normed space. $(X_n)_n$ is a sequence of finite dimensional subspaces of $X$ and $X_n\subset X_{n+1}$ and $X$ is the closure of the union of all $X_n$.

Show that there exists a sequence of linear functionals $f_n\in X^{*}$ such that $\left\Vert f_n \right\Vert=1$ and $f_n(x)=0$ for all $x\in X_n$. Show also that $f_n(z)$ converges to $0$ for any $z\in X$.

I defined $f_n:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $f_n(x)=0$ if $x\in X_n$ and $f_n(x)=1$ if $x\notin X_n$. The norm equals to 1 is quite easy but I have problem showing that my $f_n$ is linear by construction.

Because if $x,y\notin X_n$, then I don't have $f_n(x+y)=f_n(x)+f_n(y)$ since the LHS is 1 and the RHS is 2 and thus I cannot claim that my $f_n\in X^{*}$.

Any advice? How to show the last part converge to $0$? Is my construction of $f_n$ correct?

Comment: You're trying to construct a linear functional based on values on a subspace, have you encountered the Hahn-Banach theorem?

Comment: Yes. How does that help here?

Comment: I know if I defined $g_n\in X_n^{*}$ then by Hahn-Banach I have $f_n\in X^{*}$ with the same norm. But I was not able to construct such $g_n$ with norm 1 since $g_n(x)$ must be zero for all $x\in X_n$

Comment: I don't think the $f_n$ you have defined is really linear, is it?

Comment: yeah...it is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X \neq X_n$ so there exists some $y \in X \setminus X_n$. Then each $X_n$ is finite dimensional, and hence is a closed convex space. In addition $\{y\}$ is a compact convex space, moreover $\{y\}$ and $X_n$ are disjoint. So by the Hahn-Banach seperation theorem (derived from the Hahn-Banach theorem, sometimes also called a geometric version) we can seperate $X_n$ and $\{y\}$ strictly by a hyperplane. In other words there exists $f_n \in X^*$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$ f_n(x) < \alpha < f_n(y) \quad \forall x \in X_n $$
But then $f_n(\lambda x) = \lambda f_n(x) < \alpha$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb {R}, x \in X_n$ so we must in fact $f_n(x) = 0$ for all $x \in X_n$. Moreover $f_n(y) > 0$ so $f_n \neq 0$ therefore we can rescale $f_n$ such that $\lVert f_n \rVert = 1$.

Now let $z \in X = \overline{\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n}$. Then $z = \lim_{i \to \infty} x_i$ for some $(x_i)_{i=1}^{\infty} \subset \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n$. It should be clear for any $x \in \cup_{n=0}^{\infty} X_n$ that $f_n (x) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, we use this along with uniform boundedness of $(f_n)$ to show $f_n (v) \to \infty$.

Given $\epsilon > 0$, $v = \lim_{i \to \infty} x_i$ therefore $\exists I$ such that $\lVert v - x_I \rVert < \epsilon$. Then $f_n (x_I) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ therefore there exists $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$ we have $\lVert f_n(x_I) \rVert < \epsilon$.

Then for all $n \geq N$ we have
$$ \lVert f_n (v) \rVert \leq \lVert f_n (v) - f_n (x_I) \rVert + \lVert f_n (x_I) \rVert \leq \lVert f_n \rVert \lVert v - x_I \rVert + \lVert f_n (x_I) \rVert < 2 \epsilon $$
Hence $f_n (v) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ as required.

Comment: when you say rescale $f_n$ you mean just define $g_n = \frac{f_n}{\left\vert f_n \right\Vert}$ to get norm 1 right? Btw, is the $\alpha$ positive?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. The $\alpha$ turns out to be positive in this case but what's important is the strict separation, we could just as easily have the inequalities flipped and have $\alpha$ negative.

Comment: One more question if you don't mind, does $X_n\rightarrow X$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ here? because if yes, then I have $f_n(z)\rightarrow 0$ for the last part of the question.

Comment: If by $X_n \to X$ you mean $X = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n$ then no, $X = \overline{\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n}$. To see the difference, consider the usual indicator sequences $e_n$ in $\ell^{1}$ and let $X_n = \text{span} \{e_1, \ldots, e_n\}$. Then $\cup_{n=0}^{\infty} X_n$ are the set of sequences which are eventually 0, however $\overline{\cup_{n=0}^{\infty} X_n} = \ell^1$.

Comment: In that case, by taking limits, I only have $f_n(x)$ converges to $0$ for all $x\in \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}X_n$. May I know how to deal with the closure?

Comment: I've now edited the answer to a complete one